# Trigger plugin event in fof

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, fof

I am working in Akeeba subscription it's based on FoF.I wanted to check some condition before user can delete subscription.

I have a plugin `MyPlugin` and class is -

```
class plgAkeebasubsMyPlugin extends JPlugin
```

I thought that I'll have to add code in function `onContentBeforeDelete` inside this plugin but it did not work.I would like to know how can I create plugin to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you checked the FOF documentation?

Comment: @Lodder:Yes,but could not get anything helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly fired, via **F0FModel** ($context = 'com_akeebasubs.subscriptions').

You can simply check it in *PlgContentJoomla / onContentBeforeDelete* (where the function is executed and returns when the context is not 'com_categories.category').

If your plugin is not being fired, check if it is enabled as System or Content plugin to receive the event.